# jquery ajax to python GAE

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, google-app-engine

I have a basic Google App Engine project using python. I would like to implement a sort of logging on my site (I do understand that google app engine has this kind of feature). Also in the future i would like to add high scores to some of my games using this same idea. For my logging i have a basic page.py that contains this:

```
from google.appengine.api import users
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
import webapp2
import json




class Save(ndb.Model):
  time = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  url=ndb.StringProperty()
  user=ndb.StringProperty()

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):


  def post(self):

    data = json.loads()
    self.stuff.url=(data)
    self.stuff.put()


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/page.py', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

This is a test before i implement the entire thing. I want to save the date, user, and page title in my logs. I know how to get the other things. I want jQuery in the html to send the page title to the python file. Here is my jQuery.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/page.py",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ('index')
    })
```

I have a good understanding of html, this is the first time i have played with jQuery and json, I have a good understanding of python as well.

My questions. How is this ajax file transfer supposed to work? I need a parameter for json.loads() what would that be, how would it work? A simple example would be greatly appreciated.

I have done google searches and stack overflow searches, but i have not found a simple explanation and example.

Thanks in advance.

Elijah

Comment: Please don't give your URLs .py suffixes. The fact that Python is powering the back end is completely irrelevant to the URLs themselves.

Comment: ok sounds good, will do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def post(self):

        data = self.request.body
        args = json.loads(data)
        .... and put the data ....
```

But why not use: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/

Or start here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uy0tP6_kWJ4

Comment: i tried what you said and got this error:  args = simplejson.loads(data)
NameError: global name 'simplejson' is not defined.  I have not yet read the doc or watched the video. Thank you for answer so quickly though.

Comment: I just looked over the docs about backends. I could do that. Seems to me it might be simpler just to stick with the json requests though.

Comment: You can use json. I'have changed my answer

Comment: I tried your new code and got the error:  raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
INFO     2015-06-01 18:39:49,798 module.py:788] default: "POST /page.py HTTP/1.1" 500 2690
.Hope i am not being too much of a pain :) thank you for your help

Comment: I was playing around with json and after a few hours i found that json.dumps(data) works. Thank you for your help